# How to create Image Grid Slider with different heights and width of image ( masonry slider )

Tags: jquery, css, reactjs, slick.js, owl-carousel

I wanted to create a grid image slider with different height and width of the image. something looks like the below image.

In the below image we have the first image slider as Squire Image and 2nd slider as two rectangle image than again Squire image and continue ...

[image]

Can anyone suggest any slider which supports this type of image configuration?

Comment: Do you need a masonry slider?

Comment: @nilesh Do those sliders need to have only one button/slider controls or can they be independent of each other? Also, any code you have already tried?

Comment: i have used the slick slider and used the same approach as @cezar-andrei-popescu mentioned in answer

but the problem is here we are limiting the image into squire or rectangle

Comment: yes @s.kuznetsov something same as masonry slider

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Swiper.js](https://swiperjs.com/) for this, adding a custom class to the `swiper-slide` elements, eg. `swiper-slide grid-squire` etc...

```html
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide grid-squire">
            <img data-src="1.jpg" class="squire-image-type-1">
            <img data-src="2.jpg" class="squire-image-type-2">
            <img data-src="3.jpg" class="squire-image-type-3"> 
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide grid-rectangle">
            <img data-src="4.jpg" class="rectangle-image-type-1">
            <img data-src="5.jpg" class="rectangle-image-type-2">
            <img data-src="6.jpg" class="rectangle-image-type-3"> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Similar to how [this](https://swiperjs.com/demos/170-slides-per-column.html) works, but instead of slides per column, elements per slide.